# Out-of-time testing (basic question)

Tags: self-study, predictive-models, sample, out-of-sample

I understand the importance of out-of-sample testing, but could you tell me **why I should (or shouldn't) do out-of-time testing** ?

The only use that comes to mind is if the predictive model applies to economic activity and seeing whether it would work in both bull and bear markets.  But more insight in the use and importance(?) of out-of-time testing would be very welcome.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your distinction... Why wouldn't "out-of-time" testing simply be another name for out-of-sample testing for time series?

Comment: That would explain why I can't find much info on 'out of time' samples.  Thank you @SteveS .  I didn't realize the two were the same, but just applied to a time series.

Comment: Oh, well in that case, glad I could help! ... Working with Time Series can get really confusing because there's a lot of stuff that is just like the basic regressions you've seen before but then there's also a lot of additional, time series-specific stuff to be mindful of. [Just sort of throwing that out there, I guess]. Anyway, a common approach to out-of-sample testing (if you have, say, two different models you want to compare) would be to calculate the **RMSE** for the two models (using that out-of-sample sample) and then choose the model with the lower **RMSE**...

Comment: This is definitely important in Finance since there's often a lot of "backtesting" that goes on (with the results of such backtesting presented as if these were actual, realized returns.

Comment: Exactly, the backtesting issue is why I didn't use k-fold cross validation for optimization, but rather a hold-out sample (the last part of data). Wouldn't want to go back in time with financial time series.

Comment: And @SteveS , besides comparing 2 models, I assume it can also serve for 1 model and seeing if it performs equally well at another point in time?  Though I don't really see the point as having a test set (not used in training/optimization of course) basically already proves the out-of-sample/time performance, no?

Comment: [This paper](http://www.aeaweb.org/articles.php?doi=10.1257/jep.28.2.3)--which is surprisingly readable and informative--discusses some of the issues that arise with the overlap of Econometrics/Time Series/Machine Learning/etc. (In fact, you can also download the datasets and scripts that the author--who is the chief economist at Google--mentions throughout the article).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This post and question is a bit old, but very relevant to what I am doing at the moment.

I am in the position where I trained and scored a random forest (rf) algorithm using weather and time-of-day to predict energy consumption of a building with time-series data. At first I took a simple out-of-sample approach and just split the samples randomly to generate my training and (withheld) test set. When scoring I got extremely high R-squared values on my test set that almost matched (with in tenths of a percent in the high 90's) the rf-training scores that the training achieved on my training set. This seemed fishy - just too good to be true.

So I cut the last few weeks out of the time series and used that as a test set instead - so out-of-time testing. Sure enough my scores fell to around 0.80 and below. It made sense when I thought about it, although those original test points were withheld, they were simply too similar (close in time and weather circumstances) to the training points to be a challenge for the prediction.

So what I learned from this, is that if there is a time component in your data, then an test out-of-time is probably going to be a much better predictor of the accuracy of your algorithm when it is confronted with new data in production, as opposed to just doing random out-of-sample testing.

Comment: Though the comments below my original post answered my question, thank you for your input.  It does indeed make sense and I hope it can help others with the same question / concerns.